# Is every binary product a binary relation?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite products. Let $X,Y$ be two objects of $\mathcal{C}$. Let's denote by $p_X,p_Y$ the projections to $X$ and $Y$ respectively. I want to prove that the product $X\times Y$ is a relation from $X$ to $Y$, in the sense that $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are jointly monic, or equivalently that the factorization $(p_X,p_Y)$ is a monomorphism. But this is just the universal property of binary products.

My question is: is it all, just so easy, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, the fact that $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are jointly monic is implied almost immediately by the universal property of products. The proof is not "just the universal property", though, since you only need the uniqueness part, not existence.

To prove that they're jointly monic, what you have to prove is that, for any two morphisms $f,g : A \to X \times Y$, if $p_X \circ f = p_X \circ g$ and $p_Y \circ f = p_Y \circ g$, then $f=g$.

The uniqueness part of the universal property tells us that
$$f = \langle p_X \circ f, p_Y \circ f \rangle \quad \text{and} \quad g = \langle p_X \circ g, p_Y \circ g \rangle$$
So it's certainly the case that if $p_X \circ f = p_X \circ g$ and $p_Y \circ f = p_Y \circ g$, then $f=g$.

Hence $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are jointly monic.